# How can I configure Hangouts call settings prior to calling?

Tags: google-hangouts

How can I configure Hangouts call settings prior to calling? E.g., if I want to select a given microphone, how can I do so before I call someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot configure Hangouts call settings prior to calling.

Also, warning from Hangouts:

> Hangouts phone calling is going away soon, but Google Voice can keep you texting and calling.